# mongodb bulk update, auto-$unset missing fields during $set

Tags: mongodb

I have this in the database before updating:

```
{'id': 1, 'updating_this': 'a', 'removing_this': 'x'}
```

now I call update:

```
item = {'id': 1, 'updating_this': b'}
bulk.find({'id': item['id']}).update({'$set': item})
```

what I get as result:

```
{'id': 1, 'updating_this': 'b', 'removing_this': 'x'}
```

what I want as result:

```
{'id': 1, 'updating_this': 'b'}
```

so basically I want the `update` command to remove all missing fields, without specifying them by an $unset operation, that is, to completely overwrite the document.

How do I go about this?

**Update** got this working with `replace_one()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `update` directly on the collection without `$set`.

```
item = {'id': 1, 'updating_this': b'}
bulk.update({'id': item['id']}, item)
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#replace-a-document-entirely

Comment: `ValueError: update only works with $ operators` this does not work with the `Bulk Write Operations`. I found the `replace_one` operator which does its job, so for me this question is answered. Thanks for your effort, though.

Comment: That error comes from an older version of mongodb. The linked documentation supports the syntax provided.

Comment: I'm on 3.2.1 as well as the latest pymongo module.

Comment: Keep in mind that the documentation you cite is talking about the collection operators.